# NSexception with sigbart error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I am trying to fetch the result from json web service. For string values it is working fine. When I try to fetch the integer value It throwing nsexeption with sigbart error.

My json result loos like this.

```
[{"CaseId":81,"ApplicantName":"test","ApplicantContactNo":"teas","PropertyAddress":"ewae","BankName":"Bank of India","ReportDispatcher":null,"PropertyType":"test","AssignedAt":"2016-10-07T13:01:20","Status":"Open","PropertyId":62,"EmployeeName":null,"StatusId":1}
```

When I try to capture the CaseId and AssignedAt it throwing error.

here is my code.

```
NSString * caseid = @"CaseId";
NSString * assigned = @"AssignedAt";
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *caseid1 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"];
    NSString *assigned1 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"AssignedAt"];
    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  caseid1,caseid,assigned1,assigned, nil];                      
    [myObject addObject:dictionary];
}
cell.caseid.text=[tmpDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"];
cell.days.text=[tmpDict objectForKey:@"AssignedAt"];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should give the error. But may guess is that there is a "[NSNumber length] unrecognized selector sent to instance". `NSJSONSerialization` transform the `NSData` into `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString` and `NSNumber`. You can check it with `[[tmpDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"] class]`. So `cell.caseid.text=[[tmpDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"] stringValue];` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
NSString *caseIdValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"]];
NSString *assignedAtValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"AssignedAt"]];
```

Comment: It is working fine. One more help ? I have value like this "2016-10-07T13:01:20". I want to convert to date like 2 days or 3days from current date. any help ?

Comment: @R.AarthikaRajendran That's another question. You have to use a `NSDateFormatter` to transform that string date into a `NSDate` (there are already question on SO about this) and then transform it into "2 days ago", etc (there is also question about it on SO).